# extending the constructor of an ndb model in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to extend the constructor of my ndb model to - on construction of the entity - create an entity from a different model setting the current entity that is being created as it's parent.

Specifically, I would like to do this:

```
class Thing(polymodel.PolyModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(Thing, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        some_other_thing = OtherThing(parent=self.key, id=self.key.id())
        some_other_thing.put()
```

If I understand this correctly, the key for Thing doesn't get assigned up until a put operation on it is performed. Thus, in my code, `self.key` will be `None` and hence this will not work.

Is there any way of referencing the future key or am I not going about this in the right way at all and my code for this (creating another entity on creation) should really go somewhere else?

Comment: Even if this was possible, it would be a bad idea. If Thing nevers calls put(), now you have orphaned data. Maybe you could use the _post_put_hook method to create OtherThing when Thing gets created?

Comment: I thought about this as well but IIUC _post_put_hook will get called also when I update the entity? One other option I am thinking of is that maybe on Thing I could create a class method create_thing that would create the thing, perform put on it and then create all other things I might need... at least this gets this bit out of my handler but not sure if this is ideal either...

Comment: If you need Thing and OtherThing created together, then I think the classmethod approach is the way to go. Prob want to run it in a transaction too

Comment: thank you Gwyn, this is what I'll do!

Comment: How about having OtherThing have a required reference to Thing as ndb.StructuredProperty(Thing, required=True) ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion David. I read up a little bit on structured properties (and will try to learn more) and I think they will be quite helpful for some aspects of what I want to achieve but not all (for example, IIUC StructuredProperty cannot have a StructuredProperty itself?). Guess I'll have to spend a bit more time on my data model :)